# Programmatically Screen Capturing on Retina / High res screens

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch, jpeg, screen-capture

Dear Scholars
I am using the following code to capture the screen and save it to a jpg inside the photo album - Which works great.

Yet, when running on iPhone 4 with a higher resolution the captured screen is only 320X480 opposing to a higher resolution (I assume this is also the case on iPad).

How should I go about with this issues?

```
// Save the captured image to photo album
- (IBAction)saveAsJPG
{

    UIImage *image = [self captureView:self.view];  
    UIImageWriteToSavedPhotosAlbum(image, self, 
           @selector(image:didFinishSavingWithError:contextInfo:), nil);
}

-(UIImage *)captureView:(UIView *)view 
{ 
    CGRect screenRect = [[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds];
    UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(screenRect.size);
    CGContextRef ctx = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext(); 
    [[UIColor blackColor] set]; 
    CGContextFillRect(ctx, screenRect);
    [view.layer renderInContext:ctx];   
    UIImage *newImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
    return newImage; 
}
```

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Use `UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions` instead of `UIGraphicsBeginImageContext`:

```
UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(screenRect.size, NO, 0.0);
```

See [Apple QA1703](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#qa/qa2010/qa1703.html) for details.